# PHP cross-domain form processing security

Tags: php, forms, security, cross-domain, captcha

I have several websites with email sign-up forms. I want to populate a central database on a different server then these websites.
I was thinking about setting the action attribute of form to a webservice which is on the central database's server. This webservice could simply save the data into the database. 
What security solutions can you recommend to avoid hacking/flooding the central server?

One of the solutions would be to check the IP / domain where the data is comming from (my websites) and if it's a different one then block that IP.

What other solutions can you recommend? Captcha would not really work here I think.

Comment: Yes I think you have to do a ip restriction to avoid cross-domain hacking, and maybe adding a hashed "password" from your websites (and checking it in the central server) to enforce the security.

Comment: The best place to post this question would be security.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to write a simple webservice, you can just set the action to the current server, and let a PHP script on that server communicate with the central database's webservice. This way, you can do authentication *and* you don't have any security complications.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, more secure, solution would be to have a server-side proxy script running on each website which forwards the form input to your central webservice along with an application secret only known to the proxy and the receiver.

Very simple implementation (untested):

**proxy.php**

```
<?php
$secret = '[RANDOMSTRING]'
$webservice = 'https://www.yourhost.com/receiver.php'
$formData = serialize($_POST);
file_get_contents($webservice . '?secret=' . $secret . '&data=' . urlencode($formData));
?>
```

**receiver.php**

```
<?php
if ($_GET['secret'] == '[RANDOMSTRING]') {
    $formData = unserialize($_GET['data']);
} else {
    // ignore
}
```

*NOTE:* As there is only server to server communication involved (harden by using https), the risk of eavesdropping is neglectable.

Comment: -1 as I don't think as this stands this would add any security at all, as all id need to do is find a form which does submit, inspect the ajax session, see in plain text your $secret and then use the reciever.php with my naughty data with said secret. Caveat to this would be if you had a trusted algorithm that could generate random strings that change each time the form loads AND this can be verified as a trusted string by the algorithm in the reciever.php

Comment: @NicholasKing You've misread the answer. There is no Ajax session. The request is from PHP to PHP. There's no client-side communication involved. Snooping is *very* hard to do in this case.

Comment: If its a webservice that i can call from my naughty website my point still stands.

Comment: @NicholasKing Your naughty website would have to guess the application secret, as it is not exposed to the user (client-side). Even a 10 character secret would take forever to guess in a bruteforce attack over https.

Comment: @NicholasKing If it is a webservice, your point becomes moot, especially when that does verification (perhaps through IP filtering/firewalling).